# \vu of physicx package with physics and unimath options went wrong when loading unicode-math package

Tags: unicode-math, physics

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[physics, unimath]{physicx}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$\vu{a}, \vu*{a}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[physics]{physicx}
% \usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$\vu{a}, \vu*{a}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\vu` in the second example is what we want. I added `unimath` option to `physicx` but it didn't work.

### Added

I'm sorry that I forgot that I installed `physicx` package manually. The github repository: https://github.com/Sophanatprime/physicx. The reason why it has not been updated to CTAN is that the author said he hadn't written the English-version document.

This package is an improvement of `physics` package.

The MWE without `physicx` package is

```latex
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[unimath, physics]{physicx}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$\vu{a}, \vu*{a}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you point to where `physicx` is available from?

Comment: @JosephWright Sorry for that, I have added details in the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you load the `unicode-math` package, you have to use `\symbf{\hat{a}}` or `\hat{\mathbf{a}}` but not `\mathbf{\hat{a}}`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\vectorunit{ s m }{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\boldsymbol{\hat{#2}}}{\symbf{\hat{#2}}}}
\begin{document}
$\vu{a}, \vu*{a}$
\end{document}
```

[image]